# Which ammeter to pick for best accuracy and why?

Tags: current-measurement, measurement

This is merely a theoretical question.
If we want to achieve the best accuracy possible while measuring electrical current and we have two digital ammeters available from two different manufacturers, which both claim to be accurate by the same order of magnitude, in what way can we determine which ammeter is more accurate?
 This is one question from my Electrical Measurements book. The only way I can think of is taking multiple measurements with both ammeters, calculating the mean value of measurements for both ammeters and comparing that value to the correct value (best estimation). And whichever one has lower absolute mistake (\$ \Delta I=I_{mean}-I_{correct}) \$ is a more accurate one. Am I right? Or there are other things to consider?

Comment: So you actually have three ammeters?

Comment: "Man with two watches never knows the right time." Man with two ammeters ...

Comment: Actually, we already have the correct value defined, so we compare the measurements of the two amms to that value.

Comment: What was the error on your "correct defined value"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That procedure will tell you which meter happens to be better calibrated for that particular value of current at that moment in time.

The manufacturer's specifications (assuming they aren't lying) cover the full range of measurements, considering things like the absolute accuracy of the internal reference, converter nonlinearities, component matching and how all of this changes over time (aging).

You can't assume that any given meter is better than its specifications based on a few measurements.

Answer (score -1):

You need to plug some more variables into your decision making equation.

Are you measuring currents greater that an amp in AC or DC?

I’ve found that I only trust Fluke clamp on meters for DC current measuring.

Are you measuring magnitudes less than an amp such as milliamps or micro amps?

My experience has been that standard non clamp multimeters which can measure current in series, provide good accuracy.  I’ve used Fluke and Extech but I’m sure there many other brands are suitable.

Comment: I'm not actually measuring anything, but lets say we need to measure DC current of magnitude less than an amp. But, lets say we have two standard non clamp digital multimeters from Fluke and Extech which both claim to have the same accuracy. How can you test which one is more accurate?

Comment: Have them both calibrated and certified to NIST standards.  Both should read with their standard tolerances.